# Cannot create an xml file in visual studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, relative-path

I am trying to create an XML file from an existing csv file.
I have checked the content of the xml, which is created successfully when I log the result in the debug console.

[image]

I plan to export the file as an xml file named

> output.xml

The code I wrote as following

```
//Export TO XML
            string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            string xml = "";
            XElement top = new XElement("WoodStock",
                                        from items in file
                                        let columns = items.Split(',')
                                        select new XElement("Item", new XElement("Code", columns[0]),
                                                                    new XElement("Description", columns[1]),
                                                                    new XElement("Count", columns[2]),
                                                                    new XElement("Order", columns[3]))
                                       );

            System.Console.WriteLine(top);

            File.WriteAllText("output.xml", xml + top.ToString());
```

I need to use a relative file path, as the assignment will be ran on the tutor's computer as well.  I plan to use put it under the same folder with the original csv file.
The relative path of the csv file is

```
var filePath = "stocklist.csv";
```

[image]

Unfortunately, after I run my program, I cannot locate the xml file as expected.  How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked on the file system rather than checking the list of files in Visual Studio?

Comment: The default write location is in the same directory as the c# executable which is in the VS bin folder.  You could include the entire pathname of the xml file so it always goes to same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "stocklist.csv");
```

Your file will be read from the directory where you launched your app. Same for writing.

Answer (score 1):

VS is buggy, not always refreshing files, so it can be that.

1. Try to exit and open VS
2. Try to create a file manually, teminal: `touch filename.xml`

Comment: You are 100% right, VS is very buggy when it comes to file handling for some reason.  The expected file was created, but it is not appearing in the explorer window; Instead, I can see the file if I open the folder manually.